# My html5 canvas and Kinetic.js code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

It's worked :  http://jsfiddle.net/qYYm5/

I recently discovered Kinetic.js from here : http://www.kineticjs.com/

I tried to follow that example, but nothing is working...

This code should draw an image "iPhoneBg.jpg" on the layer "background_layer". Needless to say my image exists.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Kinetic.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            //INITIALISATION
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: "iPhone",
                width: 480,
                height: 720
            });
            //LAYERS
            var background_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var sms_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var text_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            //ELEMENTS
            var iPhoneBg_image = new Kinetic.Image({
                image: 'iPhoneBg.jpg'
            });
            //DRAWING
            background_layer.add(iPhoneBg_image);
            stage.add(background_layer);
        };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="iPhone" width="480" height="720"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload = function() {
        //INITIALISATION
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "iPhone",
            width: 480,
            height: 720
        });
        //LAYERS
        var background_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var sms_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var text_layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        //ELEMENTS
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            var iPhoneBg_image = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imageObj
            });
            //DRAWING
            background_layer.add(iPhoneBg_image);
            stage.add(background_layer);
        }
        imageObj.src = "iPhoneBg.jpg";
    };

<body><div id="iPhone"></div></body>`

Comment: Use **"<div id="iPhone"></div>"** instead **"<canvas id="iPhone" width="480" height="720"></canvas>**
" in Body Tag

Comment: Oh sorry i don't saw this correction, thanks very much for you help !

Comment: ok, and i had another question if you can awswer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957042/how-to-crop-an-image-with-canvas-and-kinetic-js